# NSInvalidArgumentException / unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app is crashing for some reason after pressing a tableView cell. It doesn't crash the first time but it crashes after couple of time navigating through the table.

Here is my console:

[image]

After doing some debugging, if I removed this line of code, it doesn't crash.

```
[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT] / 30
```

Here is my viewDidLoad for DetailViewController:

```
titleLabel.text = [newsArticle objectForKey:@"Series"];
timeLabel.text = [newsArticle objectForKey:@"Duration"];
guestsLabel.text = [newsArticle objectForKey:@"Guests"];
descTextView.text = [newsArticle objectForKey:@"Content"];
```

"newsArticle" is: NSDictionary variable.

Any ideas why is this happening? Any advice will be appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: That's not the line causing the crash. Post your `-[DetailViewController viewDidLoad]` method.

Comment: Looks to me like you are setting a UITextView's `text` property to an object of type `NSNull`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue:

There were some items that weren't available on all options so I I used this code to prevent it from crashing and letting the user know that there is no data available:

```
if (![dictionary objectForKey:@"Guests"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    gueststxt.text = [newsArticle objectForKey:@"Guests"];
} else {
    gueststxt.text = @"No Data";
}
```

Just posted this in case someone comes across this issue.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message states, you are attempting to basically call `setText:` with `NSNull` instead of a string;  i.e. `[someTextView setText:[NSNull null]];`.

Frame #7 is from your app, which is called **JSON**.  So, assuming you are loading a JSON document.

Your JSON document has a  NULL value where your code expects there to be a string.  Go look at the JSON and figure out where the document contains an unexpected construct.

While fixing your JSON document is part of the solution, I would also suggest hardening your code against such failures.